# What JS error help prevent with typescript error when it is Functions that return promises must be async @typescript-eslint/promise-function-async

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I feel like this is not necessary. Is this error rule is to prevent promise that return, no error? What does this error help with?

I read the official doc https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/promise-function-async.md

But I do not understand what does it really mean here:

> non-async Promise - returning functions are technically capable of either. Code that handles the results of those functions will often need to handle both cases, which can get complex

Is the `both` referring to is resolve or reject or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paraphrasing the description in [the rule's documentation](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/promise-function-async.md): if a function can both throw a synchronous error and return a rejected promise, it's tough to write code to handle that. This rule ensures that a function either does one, or the other, never both.

For example, if a function might have both a synchronous and an asynchronous error, then handling them needs to be something like this:

```
function example (obj) {
  // this might throw synchronously
  const result = JSON.stringify(obj);
  // This might reject (asynchronously)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
     resolve(result);
   } else {
     reject('too bad');
   }
  });
}

try {
  example({ foo: 'bar' })
    .catch(err => {
      // Have to split my error handling to two places, not one    
    });
} catch (err) {
 // Have to split my error handling to two places, not one
}
```

Instead of just one catch

```
example({ foo: 'bar' })
  .catch(err => {
    // All error handling in one place
  });
```

As with all lint rules, if you don't find it useful, feel free to disable it.

Comment: so IOW, its only allowing to returning a rejected promise, and NO throw error. correct? can you give an example of how an code complexity got prevented by this rule?

Comment: Yeah. It's about making sure that if the happy path is going to return a resolved promise, then the sad path will return a rejected promise (and not throw)